# get ALL the issues with a certain label, not just the open ones

Tags: github-api

I am trying to get all of the issues for https://github.com/ropensci/drake with a "Frequently Asked Question" label. The following gives me all the open issues with any label.

```
curl -i -u wlandau https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/drake/issues
```

In addition to filtering on a label, I need the *closed* issues too, not just the open ones. I looked at the [documentation for `state`](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#parameters), but I still don't know where to put it in the query. I am a GitHub API beginner. I know how to copy existing examples, but I do not actually know how to write my own queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can append it as a query parameter after the `?` character:

```
curl -i -u wlandau https://api.github.com/repos/ropensci/drake/issues?state=all
```

Comment: Hmmm.... that's in improvement, but there are 211 issues, and the query above only gives me 30.